# Sorting an array by corresponding ranges

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

My purpose is to populate an array from `list`:

```
list = [-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15]
```

in an order following this:

- Individual integers not followed by its incremented value (by 1) will be added directly to the result array.
- Integers which is followed by its incremented value (by 1) will be added to the range array and this array will then be added to result and will be reset again to be used for the next range.

The correct output should be:

```
solution(list)
# => [-6, [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1], [3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13], 15]
```

My code and my output is below.

```
def solution(list)
  result = []
  idx = 0
  loop do
    range = []
    loop do
      if list[idx+1] - list[idx] == 1
        range << list[idx]
        idx += 1
      else
        result << list[idx]
        idx += 1
        break
      end
    end
    result << range
  break if idx == list.size - 1
  end
  result
end 

solution(list)
# => [-6, [], 1, [-3, -2, -1, 0], 5, [3, 4], 10, [7, 8, 9], 13, [12]]
```

The code is not correct. Can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Your code is *completely* broken... I wouldn't bother stepping through it to debug; I'd just rewrite it.

Comment: Also, I get that this is an algorithm challenge, but under "normal circumstances" you can just make use of ruby's extensively expressive language - e.g. `list.slice_when { |prev, curr| curr != prev.next }.to_a`

Comment: Hint: Try testing your method with a variety of different inputs. Try giving it an empty array, or an array with 1 element, or an array where all elements are consecutive, or where none are consecutive, .... It's much easier to debug problems with a variety of inputs covering more edge cases.

Comment: This is the first time I ran across slice_when method actually and it seems to be fitting perfectly with this kind of sortings. I tried to solve it in an iterative way but it didn't work. Thanks for this short method.

Comment: I'd still highly recommend that you try to implement this "manually", if that was the whole point of the exercise... Ruby's rich library makes writing concise code very easy, but I was under the impression that this was an *algorithm* challenge.

Comment: Yes, this is part of an algorithm challenge, not all of it but the important part. I will also try to solve it manually so I am trying to improve my natural ability to solve algorithms with arrays. I have to admit that I am amazed to meet slice_when method and I also used it to solve another similar problem. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `chunk_while`.

```
list.chunk_while{|a, b| a.next == b}.map{|a| a.one? ? a.first : a}
# => [-6, [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1], [3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13], 15]
```